# Teams Auth: How to retrieve the token response after oAuth login?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm following the [46.teams-auth sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/46.teams-auth) to authenticate the user in Microsoft Teams. I'm able to authenticate the user and I can see the token received in the waterfall dialogue step.

I want to know how can we access that token in the turn context to make authenticated requests. For example, when the loggedin user types "create:task", in this message context, I should be able to get the user token and use it for finishing the task on the third party API which supports AAD.

I have looked at [getAadTokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/botbuilder/botframeworkadapter?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#getaadtokens-turncontext--string--string---) with the connection name, [getUserToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/oauthprompt?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#getusertoken-turncontext--string-) but not sure how to get the token from the turn context.

Any pointers to get this done would be great.

Comment: You need to store the auth token somewhere to access it. Are you looking to make graph API call?

Comment: I'm trying to make requests to the backed which accepts AzureAD tokens. Isn't it available in the turn context? May I know the recommended place to store the token?

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924550/how-to-fetch-user-access-token-after-authentication-in-microsoft-teams-bot & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107010/microsoft-teams-authentication-unable-to-retrieve-token-in-teams-bot-v4-sdk

Comment: I checked these before but unable to figure out how to make use of the token in the turn context of other commands.